# Getting Results from Sql Section by Section

Tags: c#, sql-server, resultset, sections

I have a question. Is there a way of getting result set from sql (like: has 15 rows in datatable) section by section(such as: i want to show results 5's so if i have 15 rows in my datatable i must have 3 section). Why do i want to do with this way? Because i have a groupbox and it has 5 richtextbox.when i divide the result set with for loop i must have three sections. i will put a next button in group box when i hit them the richtextboxes will be cleared and the second part of the result set(6,7,8,9,10) will be appear in richtextboxes seperately. im waiting your solutions in c#

Comment: Why not store the result from the query in a DataTable and go from there? No need to query the server three times with an overly complicated query.

Comment: I don't know whether I understand correctly, but do you mean something like this? `select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1) / 5 AS Section FROM MyTable`

Comment: Yes like this way. i have a sql query like that i will fetch the result: select ID,SahisSoruBaslik from [Ifade.SahisSoru] where SorusturmaNumarasi='"+DGV.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"' ORDER BY ID. Could you arrange me this query with your query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using offset keyword in T-SQL if you are using SQL Server 2012.

e.g.

```
SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name FROM Employees ORDER BY First Name OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

You can pass number of rows and offset rows as parameter as well.

For SQL Server 2008 you may try using row number:

```
SELECT some_field
FROM   (
          SELECT some_field, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_id) AS rownum
          FROM   table
       ) AS t
WHERE  t.rownum BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

Comment: no im using sql server 2008 but i have a question if a use OFFSET how can i fetch the result set and i must put where clause in sql word. Can you tell me?

Comment: @HasanYaman I am not sure what do you mean by "SQL Word"?

In case of Offset you don't need any additional where clause (other than filters required by your base set of data ofcourse).

Comment: Sorry Kasim. Normally i use a sql query like this; select ID,SahisSoruBaslik from [Ifade.SahisSoru] where SorusturmaNumarasi='"+DGV.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"' ORDER BY ID. i cant understand your query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using jquery Data table try with this

http://www.datatables.net/ .here you can set parameters as you wish.

Comment: it is simply like datatable that what i dont want to do. because i use richtextbox(for DGV or DataTable in jquerys each row)